# Cellular Data Options in Trinidad and Tobago

Tags: data-plans

I'm making my first trip to Trinidad and Tobago this holiday season with a few friends and the idea came up of trying to purchase a mobile hotspot. I've done some googling but the two major cell carriers I looked at (Digicel, bmobile) were more phone oriented (although they do offer data plans).

Just wondering if someone had more information about the data options there. I'm assuming if there is a will there is a way, I just want to make sure I take the most efficient option!

We will be there for about a week, and likely won't use more than a gigabyte or two of data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have never been to Trinidad.

[Digicel](http://www.digiceltt.com/) is a mobile telephone/internet provider in many Caribbean countries. I have had good experiences with digicel outside Trinidad. 
I would suggest to give them a try.